# Given a prefix, return top N searched words with this prefix

Tags: string, data-structures, autocomplete, prefix, trie

I was asked this question during an interview. The problem is a google-search auto-complete suggestions.

Given a prefix, the function should return the top N (constant) searched words with this prefix, i.e the N words that were searched the most times in the past, selected from all the words with this prefix that were searched ever.

For example: for the prefix "ab", N=3, and all the words with this prefix that were searched are:

- abc - 1 time
- abcd - 1 time
- abcde - 5 times
- abgh - 6 times
- abnm - 3 times

The function should return abcde,abgh,abnm.

I thought about trie tree but struggled with getting the top searched words from it.

Comment: No language tag? Or you just need an algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You thought in the right direction, however along with the Trie you should use another data structure like a heap to store the frequencies/count of the words. So using trie you can identify the words and using heap you pull the top N.